# About hole diameter size, tin diameter size and solder mask diameter size for pad of through hole components in Altium PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, orcad

Is there any rule  that relate the tin diameter size and solder mask diameter size with the hole diameter size for the pad of through hole components in Altium PCB design?

Comment: Altium has good support groups and this site isn't an altium support group so it's baffling why you posted here.

Comment: Soldermask diameter is not related to hole diameter

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Ok,is there any rule that control solder mask  diameter size,.?

Comment: Are you asking what combinations of these parameters are manufacturable? Or have you already asked your fab shop that, and you now want to know how to set up the DRC rules in Altium to enforce your fab's requirements?

Comment: @Andyaka, we answer Altium questions all the time.

Comment: @ThePhoton i want to konw,when desiging the altium pcb...is this any rule to adjust the tin diameter size and the sold er mask diameter size?

Comment: Not in front of my work computer to check the exact locations, but look for the design rules for "minimum annular ring" and "solder mask expansion".

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you sir.....